# How do I automatically add values to specific multiline texts on Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Okay, so, I've been finding ways on how to work efficiently. I'm currently working on a data entry task that requires a lot of text editing and cell-to-HTML conversions.

I've been using Tableizer a lot, which has been a real life-saver, but it can be quite tedious to convert every single cell manually.

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a basic template out of Tableizer's HTML code so I can apply some data to it.

Here's an example of the data I need to convert to HTML:

--

6.5MM X12.7MM ALUM/STEEL RIVET

DESCRIPTION :

- Carton Qty: 10
- Head Type: Peel Head
- Head Finish: 5052 Grade Aluminium
- Packaging Type: Trade Box Pack
- Finish: 5052 Grade Aluminium
- Minimum Qty: 1+

--

And here it is in HTML:

```
<style type=""text/css"">
        table.tableizer-table {
                font-size: 12px;
                border: 1px solid #CCC; 
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        } 
        .tableizer-table td {
                padding: 4px;
                margin: 3px;
                border: 1px solid #CCC;
        }
        .tableizer-table th {
                background-color: #104E8B; 
                color: #FFF;
                font-weight: bold;
        }
</style>
<table class=""tableizer-table"">
<thead><tr class=""tableizer-firstrow""><th>6.5MM X12.7MM ALUM/STEEL RIVET</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>DESCRIPTION :</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Carton Qty: 8</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Diameter: 1/4</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Qty: 200</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Diameter (mm): 12.7</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Length (mm): 19.1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Max Grip: 12.7</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Head Type: Dome Head</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Head Finish: 5050 Grade Aluminium</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Packaging Type: Trade Box Pack</td></tr>
 <tr><td>• Finish: 5050 Grade Aluminium</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I tried to create a template out of it by using a simple concatenation formula. I broke down the data into three parts: a. Header, b. Subtitle, and c. Bullet Descriptions.

Essentially, it should be like this:

```
<style type=""text/css"">
        table.tableizer-table {
                font-size: 12px;
                border: 1px solid #CCC; 
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        } 
        .tableizer-table td {
                padding: 4px;
                margin: 3px;
                border: 1px solid #CCC;
        }
        .tableizer-table th {
                background-color: #104E8B; 
                color: #FFF;
                font-weight: bold;
        }
</style>
<table class=""tableizer-table"">
<thead><tr class=""tableizer-firstrow""><th>(HEADER)</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>(SUBTITLE)</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>(BULLET DESCRIPTION)</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

This format works but I can't seem to figure out how to add the TR and TD tags ( ) for every bullet description, just like the Tableizer code above. What formula do you think I should use?

Hope someone can help me. Thank you!